# What is the right way to send a password through JavaScript AJAX to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have tried a few methods, I have confirmed that it's a special character problem ie. I tried a simple password combination that only included letters/numbers and that worked.

Since I stopped using jQuery this is the first time I've had a problem where password_verify would not work. I did make sure as I mentioned above it wasn't anything wrong with password_verify.

So I get my password input and I join it with the username like this:

```
var params = null,
    paramObj = {};
paramObj['user'] = loginInpUser.value;
paramObj['pass'] = loginInpPass.value;
params = encodeURI('post_params='+JSON.stringify(paramObj));
```

On the PHP side I receive this in POST like so:

```
$post_params = json_decode($_POST['post_params'], true);
$user = $post_params['user'];
$pass = $post_params['pass'];
```

I did make sure I get matching values from what I send on the client side, to what PHP gets ie. echo out $user and $pass, they match exactly... the special characters in question are:

```
)(#$$%)(
```

I haven't even tried to throw in a & in there which may cause problems with how you concatenate the parameters before sending them with an XMLHttpRequest.

So what is the right way to do this where special characters are still parsed correctly (password_verify matches hash with password)?

There is a reason to not use jQuery for me it was to lower file download speed-use async tags.

Edit:

Weird thing with hashes:

I just needed a basic login system so I didn't bother with a register form, I created a hashing function that used password_hash and inserted it into a db. I noticed that using

```
$pass = "password with special chars";
```

Would fail, the error would say that something inside the string was an undefined variable (string is cut up, I guess a parsing error).

But using

```
$pass = 'password with special chars';
```

This was fine.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI "Note that encodeURI by itself cannot form proper HTTP GET and POST requests, such as for XMLHTTPRequests, because "&", "+", and "=" are not encoded, which are treated as special characters in GET and POST requests. encodeURIComponent, however, does encode these characters."

Comment: Side note: That's a weird reason to not use jQuery. You could use another, smaller library like Axios - it's silly to do your own XMLHTTPRequests creation.

Comment: I tried that as well, encodeURIComponent, thanks for the link I will check it out. There's also the question of do I then use urldecode on the PHP side with either of these cases. I think not for the first case (using urlencode).

Comment: I understand it might seem weird, but our application deploys in a place where network speed is 0.5Mbps or lower. 1KB file takes almost an entire second to download. It has made some problems as I'm so used to using jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either send the entire request as JSON, or URL-encoded; a mix of both is rather weird:

```
var params = 'user=' + encodeURIComponent(loginInpUser.value) + '&pass=' + encodeURIComponent(loginInpPass.value);
```

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
```

Or:

```
var params = JSON.stringify({ user: loginInpUser.value, pass: loginInpPass.value })
```

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo $params['user'], $params['pass'];
```

This properly preserves arbitrary "special" characters correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work finally. I ended up using the second version.

Comment: I did want to mention, for some reason when generating hashes, if I set $pass equal to a string encased by double-quotes on PHP side, it fails, but using single-quotes and hash/store in db, the password matches... I don't know what's up with that. I'll add it to my question for anybody who happens to have this problem as a potential thing to check.